# what does //go:build xxx and // +build xxx means in golang?

Tags: go, build

I always see the code,

```
//go:build linux
// +build linux
```

what mean? I don't understand.

just give me some examples

Comment: Imagine you need to compile a linux-specific code, using some linux-specific api.

Comment: More than this: you can define build tags to do some alternative builds like… run integration tests, use some mock / debug / testing implementations, etc. it is the “equivalent” to #ifdef in C preprocessor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are build constraints, see https://pkg.go.dev/go/build#hdr-Build_Constraints

In older versions of Go, you would say

```
// +build linux
```

where the new syntax from Go 1.17 and up is

```
//go:build linux
```

but they do the same thing: only include this file in the Linux build.